# getAuthToken doesn't call AccountManagerCallback

Tags: android, gmail

My code works once the user authenticates my app to view and manage mails.

[image]

Or looks something like this:

[image]

However, for the first time (for the first request), Google's dialog shows up(above) and ask the user to authenticate, then AccountManagerCallback is never called even if the user selects 'OK' (Even 'Cancel' should return some value)

Here's my code:

```
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(mAccount, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/", null, mActivity, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
```

And AccountManagerCallback code:

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
               // Do something useful
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, my code works(AccountManagerCallback does get called) once the user selects 'OK' on the above dialog. Then call 'getAuthToken()' method again.

---

Above issue is found on Kitkat (Samsung Tab Pro 8.4) but not on Jelly Bean (Galaxy Nexus). Not sure if it's Kitkat vs. Jelly Bean issue or Samsung vs. Nexus issue.

If it is a bug, is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in KitKat. Google dialog is showed as a separate activity.
Try using something like that:

```
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(mAccount, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/", null, false, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
```

Then

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {

    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
           // Do something useful
            Bundle bundle;
            bundle = result.getResult();        

            Intent launch = (Intent)bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
            if (launch != null) {                   
                launch.setFlags(0);
                mainActivity.startActivityForResult(launch, AUTHORIZATION_CODE);    
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == AUTHORIZATION_CODE) {
            // request token here again 
    }
}
```